# CodeIgniter foreach running twice while using Google Chrome to execute the code

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, foreach

The problem is whenever I use any other browser then it works fine but when I use google chrome then it inserts each and every value twice. I have no clue why and how. Let me share a piece of code for your better understanding.

```
foreach($this->input->post() as $k => &$v):
    $data = array(
        'emp_survey_id' =>$k,
        'suggestion' => $this->input->post('suggestion'),
        'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
        'user_rating'=>$v
    );

    $this->survey_model->saveRating($data);
endforeach;
redirect('survey/thank_you');
```

Comment: PHP won't differ between browsers since it's all server side. Check if the data is sent to the server twice when using Chrome. Show us how the data is submitted and do a `var_dump($this->input->post())` to see what it actually contains.

Comment: I have checked Firefox, Microsoft Edge to submit the same form. Every other browser is working fine and inserts only one entry for one item but whenever I user chrome it makes 2 entries for each reocrd.

array(6) {
  [4]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["suggestion"]=>
  string(2) "ss"
}

Comment: Like I said, PHP is a _server side_ language. It's executed on the _server_ and will simply act on the data it gets. If something differs between browsers, it's more likely that the issue is how the data is submitted to the server than PHP acting differently depending on the browser. So again, please show us _all_ the relevant code (the form and any javascript involved)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your suggestion. I removed javascript validation of the form and now it's working fine. I guess chrome was somehow submitting the form twice...I guess. :|

Comment: Might be you click button twice or send request multiple times, otherwise it not related to browser, if it works in one browser then it should work in another browser.